# Clipboard Manager for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, clipboard

Following this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/13258/whats-the-best-simple-clipboard-manager-available)

I use [ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) on Windows for clipboard management, however I've got a mac-mini for iphone dev and I am missing the clipboard manager.  Anyone got any good suggestions for a decent simple mac clipboard manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/).

Comment: Does one thing well; I like it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

I have actually now started using [Clippings](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clippings-cute-clipboard-manager/id413874405?mt=12) from the app store. It's $2.99 and worth it.

[image: Picture.png]

[image: Picture 1.png]

The reasons I decided to stop using PTHPasteboard were that it is a little buggy and I tried to send feedback to the author but never heard anything. Also it is expensive at $25. Wish the author was continuing development and taking requests for a couple of UI/UX fixes, but until then I really like "Clippings"

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm coming from Windows and LOVED the [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) clipboard manager. It was SO SIMPLE and powerful. Wish I could find the same thing for Mac.

I first tried `ClipMenu`and `Jumpcut`, and have also tried using `Quicksilver`'s built in clipboard manager. I have not been too happy with any of them. I also looked at a few articles describing the so called best clipboard manager for mac, like [this one](http://gigaom.com/apple/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/). The closest one I could find was [Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/Clyppan-Clipboard-Manager-for-the-Mac/) ($5) until I found this question and tried [PTH Pasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/) as Mark had suggested.

Here's the functionality that I loved about Ditto:

- It can manage text or images, but it has an option to only keep track of text, which was important to me.
- It has an option so that text is always pasted as plain text (removes formatting)
- You can change the shortcut keys to anything you want. I prefer `cmd+shift+v` on mac.
- When activated it showed a list of clipping, typing text would filter the results to only show matches. Using the up or down arrow keys (or a number key - results were numbered) would choose the selection, and enter would paste it. Clyppan has this, but you have to activate it, press cmd+f to search, type in your string, then press tab about 4 times, then you can use the arrow keys. Too much work.
- Clyppan also has a "rapid paste" feature that I like - you can paste the last several things on the clipboard in reverse order. I think Ditto did this as well. Haven't figured out how to do that yet with [PTH Pasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/) but I'm not sure it is impossible.

If Clyppan would just fix the shortcut keys so that I could search and select clips more easily I would highly recommend it - otherwise i'd say [PTH Pasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/) is much more powerful and by far my favorite choice.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use [JumpCut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: (Jumpcut hasn't been updated since this comment was posted, so if you're a visitor from the present, keep that in mind!)

Comment: And I switched to [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) for launching & clipboard management a while ago.

Comment: @DougHarris I'm always curious about Alfred, since I do use it for launching, but anyway... I just started using http://www.apprywhere.com/copy-em-paste.html about two months ago and it's insanely good. (And I'm pretty sure dev'ing an app on the MAS is a thankless job, which is why I'm commenting here)

Answer (score 4):

My current pick is [PTH Pasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/).  I like the ability to run scripts, any flavor you want (applescript, bash, python, perl, etc...) on what I am pasting. And multiple filters can come in handy.

I bought the pro version after trying it for about 10 minutes.  I used to use CopyPaste Pro, but they fell way behind during the transition to MacOS X and that doesn't have some features that I consider essential.

Comment: Free version is no longer available for download. You have to use PRO version, which gives you only 30-days for free (in demo mode).

Comment: And now the whole site is dead and probably the app

Answer (score 3):

Application launchers [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/projects/quicksilver.html) and [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) both have integrated clipboard managers.

Comment: +1 these two apps are extremely useful for many tasks, including clipboard management. I find it hard to use a mac without one of these installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CuteClips](http://cuteclips3.com/) or [Stuf](http://www.theescapers.com/stuf/). Personally I prefer Stuf.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

- [Clipboard Evolved](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/productivity_tools/clipboardevolved.html)
- [CopyPaste Pro](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/productivity_tools/copypastepro.html)

I believe XCode also comes with a clipboard manager.

To just view what is in the clipboard:

In the Finder, go to Show Clipboard, under Edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is exactly what your looking for but take a look at pastebot.  I also has a companion iPhone app so that you can paste stuff from your iPhone to your mac.

Answer (score 0):

I use CuteClips 3 or [Butler](http://www.manytricks.com/butler/)'s Pasteboard.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CmdVees](http://cmdvees.wuonm.com). I've developed it to have a clipboard helper powerful enough and **as simple as possible**. It has just everything I need and use.

It has a quite unique feature: when you paste something, it's removed from clipboard history. This makes copy/pasting multiple bits of text much quicker. I can't work without it, YMMV.

Comment: if they had a way to activate and search the list of clips, and an option to to remove history that would be nice

Comment: @cwd there is shortcut to remove (clear) history, also right-click in the icon, it'll show additional menu options, press Opt to see alternate menu with Clear all.

Answer (score 0):

[Keeeb](http://keeeb.com/) - *The Next Generation Content Curation.*

Organise, save, sort and share whatever you find on the web.

As its web based can be used on other computing platforms as well.