# Pasting multiple snippets back-to-back?

Tags: macos, productivity, workflow

How can I copy and paste a sequence of snippets (e.g., if copying information across tabs/windows, pasting individually copied snippets so that the different snippets, in order of the copying sequence, paste)...

For example, if I copy snippets A, B, & c, how can I paste each of these snippets without returning to the text to re-copy A & B after pasting C?

Comment: Use a clipboard manager? https://superuser.com/questions/63597/clipboard-manager-for-mac

Comment: Or paste them into a text editor such as TextEdit in the desired order, then copy and paste elsewhere.

Comment: I mean without needing to go back and copy each individually so that if you’re thinking about a string of items you can control paste them consecutively in their original order. This could be useful if working across multiple applications.